# use a computed property for an indexer in typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is [a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=47&pln=19&pc=51#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJxAVwA4CECeMC8MA8AKgDQwDSMApgB5SVgAmEMA1pZiAGYyEB8AFCABcPANoBdUhEoAbSsCggEI-gEs6AWxGEAlLl5iy4nSIBK8pQ3zQEqsHFKEJBnAYDeAKBgxQkWAkooMwsEKxs7BzFxFxg3AF8Abg8vGE4lGH5faCo5DXpYLhgQPU9vbyzYNmw8fmk5BSV+WUo8sCg9AENmZDAWMBAAdzBO5nD7JJTvAHkAIwAreSgAOi6IVTgwfgCoUjcYUSrxFW2D9nEYAB8L-eMl32AOqCbc-L04nSTvOOTvbeQEMAwbZJRLJCowDoIBAdar7SZlbx7KoiADkVQAjCjSAA3DoyZCUVG4-GUTEwOLEeEIpHsVFVABMWJgxIJRLxBMZ5MpCOprFpMDR7ExOPZhIFLMoAGYUVyqTBxBMsiA5EsZCA4PxECgMJh+JDoZhSFtBnpXEDBksqjpRILMJjjEA) and here is the code:

```
const groupBy = <T, K extends keyof T>(o: T[], selector: (item: T) => T[K]): Record<string, T[]> => {
  const ret: Record<string, T[]> = {};

  for (const element of o) {
    const key = (selector(element) as unknown) as string;

    Object.assign(ret, { [key]: (ret[key] || []).concat(element) });
  }

  return ret;
};

const array = [
        { key: 'key1', value: 'value1' },
        { key: 'key2', value: 'value2' },
        { key: 'key1', value: 'value3' },
      ];

console.log(groupBy(array, (row) => row.key)['key1'])
```

I had to do this with the key:

```
const key = (selector(element) as unknown) as string;
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: do you want to support key having record values, like this
`const array = [
  { key: { a: 'key1' }, value: 'value1' },
  { key: 'key2', value: 'value2' },
  { key: { a: 'key1' }, value: 'value3' }
]

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `selector` to return `T[K] & string` via [intersection operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types):

```
const groupBy = <T, K extends keyof T>(o: T[], selector: (item: T) => T[K] & string): Record<string, T[]> => {
  // ...

  for (const element of o) {
    //  ...

    // no type assertion needed anymore
    Object.assign(ret, { [key]: (ret[key] || []).concat(element) });
  }

  return ret;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJxAVwA4CECeMC8MA8AKgDQwDSMApgB5SVgAmEMA1pZiAGYyEB8AFCABcPANoBdUhEoAbSsCggEI-gEs6AWxGEAlLl5iy4mADIY0BKrBwdIgErylDfBatxShCQZwGA3gCgYGFBIWARKKHtHBGdXaw8vXBhfAF8Abn9AmE4lGH4Q6Co5DXpYLhgQPQCgoILYNmw8aTkFJX5ZShKwKB0MrKCAeQAjACt5KAA6AEMICFU4MH5wqFJfGFEG8RVljfZjAB999fEdCZDgKah24tK9FN6slMyg5eQEMBhljPTMupgphAIKaNdb9GpBNYNEQAcgaAEZoaQAG5TGTISgwlFoygImApYhg8GQ9gwhoAJkRMCx6MxqPRFLxBPBRNYJJgsPYCORdIx7OplAAzNDGYSYOI%20gUQHIJjIQHB%20IgUBhMPwAUDMKQliAAO56HyfHUTBo6UQczAIk5AA)

---

The reason, why type assertion `(selector(element) as unknown) as string;` previously was needed, is that `key` got type `T[K]`. TypeScript cannot resolve `T[K]` further, so it cannot be used as key for an object literal. Following error is triggered:

> A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.(2464)

Comment: But this adds one problem, I can pass anything in the `selector` function now e.g `groupBy(array, (row) => 'any_key')` will be valid but only keys can be `key1` or `key2`.

Comment: I guess, what you noticed is: OP did not add `as const`, so `array` currently is not narrowed. Having changed that line, the compiler errors properly for unknown keys ([example](https://tsplay.dev/lm0xPm)). Note that you currently also can set record values like `value1` because of `T[K]` selector return type. I am not sure, if this is intended, but that's just how the question example is made up.